# Will all points inside the FOV be reachable by this vector?

Tags: vector-spaces

I am trying to find a way to randomly spawn objects within the FOV (field of view) of a player camera inside a video game. All the objects will be spawned at the same z-height so I will only be looking at a 2D coordinate system with a x- and y-axis.

The first case I looked at is when the player FOV is 90 degrees. In this case I can define two units vectors $e_1$ and $e_2$ along the edge of the FOV. By then multiplying the unit vectors with two numbers $a,b \in [0, \infty)$ I can reach any point located in between the unit vectors/FOV. [The red dot is just a random point which can be reached by multiplying the unit vectors with a and b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWC3e.png) I will randomly generate a and b and set a upper limit for how big they can get depending on how far away I want the objects to spawn within the game.

But the FOV will not always be 90 degrees in the game. What I am unsure of is if this method of creating two unit vectors along the edge of the FOV will also work for other FOVs. Will for example a vector $ae_1 + be_2$ be able to reach any point inside the FOV in the picture below (using the same conditions for a and b as previously defined)? [The red dots are random points within the FOV.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnLxc.png)

I'm guessing this will work as long as I make sure $e_1$ and $e_2$ are linearly independent? (which they will be for FOVs $\in [60, 180)$).